# Undefined binding detected when compiling SELECT query:

Tags: mysql, node.js, orm, bookshelf.js

I'm new at bookshelf.js and i'm trying to build a one to many relation from two tables and when i want to fetch the data from postman it throws me the following error:

"Undefined binding(s) detected when compiling SELECT query: select `customer_order_line`.* from `customer_order_line` where `customer_order_line`.`id_order_line` in (?)"

here is my data model for customer_order:

```
 var customer_order = db.Model.extend({
    tableName: 'customer_order',
    hasTimestamps: true,

    orders : function() {
        return this.hasMany('order_line', 'id_order_line');
    },

    payment : function() {
        return this.belongsTo('payment','id_payment');
    }

})

module.exports = db.model('customer_order', customer_order);
```

customer_order_line:

```
var order_line = db.Model.extend({
    tableName: 'customer_order_line',


    product : function(){
        return this.belongsTo('Product','id_products');
    },

    order : function(){
        return this.belongsTo('customer_order','id_customer_order');
    }
})

module.exports = db.model('order_line', order_line);
```

and here's my function that fetches the data:

```
 getOrders: function(req, res, next) {
    Customer_orders.forge()
    .fetch({withRelated: ['orders']})
    .then(function (collection){

      res.json({
        error : false,
        data : collection.toJSON()
      });
    })
    .catch(function (err){
      res.status(500)
      .json({
        error : true,
        data: {message: err.message}
      });
    });
  }
```

mysql tables:

```
CREATE TABLE customer_order (
            id_customer_order INT AUTO_INCREMENT NOT NULL,
            id_employee INT NOT NULL,
            id_payment INT NOT NULL,
            total DECIMAL(10,2) NOT NULL,
            status NUMERIC(11) NOT NULL,
            created_at TIMESTAMP NOT NULL,
            updated_at TIMESTAMP NOT NULL,
            PRIMARY KEY (id_customer_order)
);

CREATE TABLE customer_order_line (
            id_order_line INT AUTO_INCREMENT NOT NULL,
            id_customer_order INT NOT NULL,
            id_products INT NOT NULL,
            cost_without_taxes DECIMAL(10,2) NOT NULL,
            cost_with_taxes DECIMAL(10,2) NOT NULL,
            final_price DECIMAL(10,2) NOT NULL,
            quantity NUMERIC(11) NOT NULL,
            total_without_taxes DECIMAL(10,2) NOT NULL,
            total_with_taxes DECIMAL(10,2) NOT NULL,
            total DECIMAL(10,2) NOT NULL,
            status NUMERIC(11) NOT NULL,
            PRIMARY KEY (id_order_line)
);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have modified your **customer_order** model as shown below

```
var customer_order = db.Model.extend({
tableName: 'customer_order',
hasTimestamps: true,

    orders : function() {
       return this.hasMany('order_line', 'id_customer_order');
       //this must contain the foreign key present inside the order_line table and not id_order_line
    },

    payment : function() {
       return this.belongsTo('payment','id_payment');
    }

})
module.exports = db.model('customer_order', customer_order);
```

The primary key and foreign key must be explicitly given while specifying relationship, if your column name don't follow the **naming conventions of** **bookshelf.js**.

Go through this tutorial blog [nodejs with bookshelfjs mysql](https://blog.ragingflame.co.za/2014/7/21/using-nodejs-with-mysql) by Qawelesizwe Mlilo.

Comment: thank you!
My tables didn't follow the naming conventions of bookshelf.js, but using idAttribute to declare my table's id column solved everything.

Comment: Welcome, If you any doubt regarding **bookshelf.js** and can't find solution for it in google search. Go through [Ghost](https://github.com/TryGhost/Ghost), developed using bookshelf.js where you can find more solution.